# Get Json data function works in Stateless Widget in the Main class but not in the Stateful Widget in a different class

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, rest

Hi I tried calling the getContacts() function in both the initState and also the WidgetBuild method but I wont get any response whereas when I tried using the same function in Stateless widget main class and calling it inside the WidgetBuild method there it works.

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Query _ref;
  bool isSearching = false;

  get reference => null;
  TabController _tabController;

  Future<void> getContacts() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    String contacts_url =
        'api url example';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic auth example';
    var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
    print(response.statusCode);
    developer.log(response.body);
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getContacts();
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
..........
.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what your intent is. If you want to use the value returned by getContacts in your build method, an option is to use a FutureBuilder. This will allow you to easily implement a control flow depending on the state of the Future. Find code below, I mocked the behavior of the getContacts method for the example.

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  Future<List<String>> getContacts() {
    return Future.value(['Contact A', 'Contact B', 'Contact C']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getContacts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final contacts = snapshot.data as List<String>;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: contacts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(contacts[index]));
            },
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is right but my problem is that i'm not getting the response from the API(status code:200) when i call the getContacts() method. But i was getting the response when i used the same method in the Main class StatelessWidget.

Comment: Did you analyze network activity to find out what the problem could be ?